# Images are not displayed in email

Tags: mailgun

[Images are not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me1qx.png)

I am using mailgun's test account to send mails. I have authorized all my users and my website. I have added my website's logo in it, but the images sent are loaded only when clicked on "display images below". Has anyone faced the same issue?